# Rejected cached data from file:

Tags: visual-studio-code, mocha.js, vscode-extensions, npm-scripts

I am currently building a Visual Studio Code extension in typescript and I want to write some tests for it. My tests work fine using the `npm test --silent` command, there are just annoying errors saying **Rejected cached data from file:** and then a file name in my AppData\Roaming\Code\CachedData folder. I tried to look up the error but the issue doesn't seem to be well documented.

FYI: VSCode extensions use mocha as their default testing framework.

Answer (score 0):

For whatever reason deleting the CachedData folder fixed the issue. Not ideal but it works.